# What is the difference between submarine terrain modeling and land terrain modeling?

Tags: modeling, terrain

I want to use Delaunay triangulation to build a submarine terrain model, but I thought about the difference between it and land terrain modeling for a long time, but I didn't want to understand the difference between them, so I want to ask you about it, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that the biggest difference between the two modeling problems is the nature of the survey data.  Clearly, it is much easier to survey terrestrial elevation data (using airborne lidar or even old-fashioned surveying techniques) than marine environments. For practical reasons, bathymetric surveys using sonar will often be collected in the forms of "track lines" such as those shown in the figure below.  Sometimes, the geometry of the data collection will introduce artifacts into your models.
[image: Survey track lines]

Also, if you are working with a closed body of water, such as a lake or reservoir, you will absolutely have to consider introducing shoreline data using a Constrained Delaunay triangulation.  The picture below illustrates what happens if you don't.
[image]

I've posted a couple of wiki articles that talk about using the Delaunay to model lake volume and reservoir capacity. You may find that some of the ideas they discuss will help you to clarify some of your own ideas.   The first article, [Using the Delaunay to Compute Lake Volume](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Using-the-Delaunay-to-Compute-Lake-Volume-Part-1) introduces some of the principles.  The second article [Using the Delaunay to Create a Reservoir Volume Model](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Using-the-Delaunay-to-Create-a-Reservoir-Volume-Model) gets into some of the special problems such as near-shore analysis.  The pictures I've included with this post come from those articles.

Hope some of this helps.